# Java Hadoop MapReduce group by different fields

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning MapReduce paradigm, and I have a CSV file with the following fields: app_name, language, review, recommended.

I would like to extract, for every language, the top 3 most reviewed applications and the % of reviews recommended.
How should the mapper and reducer job work?

Do I need multiple map and reduce task?

Answer (score 0):

To count all reviews for each language requires one mapper+reducer

With the total counts, you can pass that to a new reducer to find the top-N and calculate percentages.

---

Overall, I'd suggest using Hive, Spark, Pig, etc not plain Mapreduce.

Comment: I am forced to use Plain MapReduce because it's a school project.
Thank you, I will try to implement it!